# Software to capture passwords automatically in Windows without asking any confirmation

Tags: windows, password-manager

I need a software to capture the passwords of websites that I log in like facebook, gmail etc. I will tell the specifications :

1. I use a Windows 7 PC. It has an admin account and a guest account. So the software should capture password in both these accounts.
2. It must be a free software.
3. It should provide access only for the administrator of the PC, but it should work on both administrator and guest accounts.
4. The software should be password protected.
5. It should be a light one.
6. It should capture multiple passwords for the same site. In my PC, multiple person use facebook. So I need to capture all that passwords.
7. It should capture all passwords without asking any confirmation. That means it should capture passwords silently, without any pop up or confirmation dialogues.

Which will be the best software of my needs ? Remember guys, I need a software that captures username and password, each time they are entered without asking any confirmation. It seems Lastpass is not suitable for me. Someone please suggest me another one.

Comment: When you say "without confirmation" you mean that you want a notification in the corner of the screen, and no waiting for a keypress or mouse-click, in order to not interrupt the workflow, right?  Because logging passwords without notification would be a malware (keylogger), not a password manager.

Comment: This cannot be done reliably. If any software claims to, do not use it. Websites ask for passwords in many different ways, sometimes even so that a password manager like Lastpass fails to provide that. Combine that with an equal number of ways to ask for password *changes*, and that 'software' you want will definitely start making mistakes, capturing and storing incorrect passwords.

Comment: Really hope you didn't find such a software, if you collect user credentials of your guests without them knowing it, it is definitely for illegal purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last Pass https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/

1. Works on Windows, Apple, and *ix OS. Smartphone for paid version. I use it seamlessly on Win 7, Win 8.1, and Ubunto.
2. Yes
3. Yes.  Uses a "trust no one" security model. See Steve Gibson's assessment on the Security Now Podcast. http://twit.tv/show/security-now/256
4. Of course.
5. Yes IMHO
6. Yes. Can set up identities. Also you can do this without using identities.
7. Yes. Also you can set it to require re-entry of master password.

Comment: Is it accessible by guest ? I want it to be invisible for guests, and also it should save all their passwords.

Comment: Is there an option in lastpass to save passwords automatically without asking confirmation ?

Comment: Guests can use the client but each would need to create their own LastPass account. Otherwise guests would be sharing passwords.

Comment: I dont know if there is the option to save without confirmation.  BTW I turn off my browser-based password saving option.

Comment: No Lastpass cannot do this without confirmation **and you don't want it to**: before you know it an incorrect password is stored.